# Why don't I get the right multiplication output?

Tags: bash, case

I don't get correct results outputted. Instead of multiplying the input to additional costs, it just displays input the way it was. I need to multiply the number of people with the additional costs they might have based on selection.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Number of Adult Tickets:(0 for none) " integer1    
read -p "Number of Junior Tickets:(0 for none) " integer2

echo ""    
echo "$integer1 Adults"    
echo "$integer2 Juniors"
echo ""

num1=$50    
num2=$20    
num3=$5    

echo "Season Pass Add-On:"    
echo "1)Add Seasonal Parking"    
echo "2)Add Season Pass For Theme Park"    
echo "7)Just Buy Tickets For Today"    
echo "8)I wanna exit."

echo ""
read -p "What would the guest like to do? " guest
echo ""    

case $guest in
    1)     
       echo "Add Seasonal Parking"     
       echo ""     
       echo "Add an additional $num1 for every adult pass"     
       echo ""      
       echo "For Adult Tickets "$(( integer1 + num1 ))""      
       echo "For Junior Tickets "$(( integer2 + num1 ))""     
       ;;    
    2)     
       echo "Add Season Pass For Theme Park"     
       echo ""     
       echo "Add an additional $num2 for every adult pass"     
       echo "Add an additional $num3 for every junior pass"     
       echo ""      
       echo "For Junior Tickets "$(( integer2 * num2 ))""      
       echo "For Adult Tickets "$(( integer1 * num3 ))""      
       echo "For Junior Tickets "$(( integer2 * num2 ))""      
       echo "For Adult Tickets "$(( integer1 * num3))""    
       ;; 
    3)     
       echo "Just buy tickets for today"     
       exit 0     
       ;;    
    4)     
       echo "invalid entry. You are exiting"     
       exit 1    
       ;; 
esac     

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the dollar signs on

```sh
num1=$50
num2=$20   
num3=$5
```

The dollar sign has a special meaning in Bash so it won't work as a regular number. Store these constants without the currency, and add it to the result afterward instead.

Dollar signs need to be escaped with a backslash to display them with echo.

```
echo "For Adult Tickets \$$(( integer1 + num1 ))"
```